# the requested member of the collection does not exist in word 2007

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have this code:

```
Dim oWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add("C:\Users\mattia\Documents\Test.dotx")
oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Hello").Range.Text = "Hello Word"
```

It produces this error:

> The requested member of the collection does not exist

why does not it work? the code is wrong or some setting in Word?

Answer (score 1):

The offending code appears to be the following

```
oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Hello")
```

It appears that there is no book mark by the name of `"Hello"` in that document.  Hence this line of code throws an exception.

To fix this you need to use the correct identifier for this book mark or add a new one if the one you want isn't present